Prove that the given function is invertible
This question is linked with this question
I have $$f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z^2,x-y+z,2x+y-z)$$ and I need to prove that it is invertible at the point $(1,-1,2)$.
I have read  that proving such a quality requires that you show that the function is bijective. However, in an exercise I found, I needed only to find the Jacobian, which is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1&2z\\
1&-1&1\\
2&1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
which is a matrix that is invertible, since the column vectors are linearly independent. But what about that point?  I thought I can  insert it in for $z$ in the Jacobian, but what about $x$ and $y$?
Thanks

Why would you not be able to show it?

You can insert $(x,y,z)=(1,-1,2)$ but the Jacobian is independent of $x,y,.$

@KurtG. Does that mean that the resulting Jacobian with $z$ inserted for is the sufficient answer to prove invertibility?

Take the 1D example $f(x)=x,.$ What is it's Jacobian and is that function invertible? You won't learn anything by asking me yes/no questions.

Yes it is invertible, and the Jacobian is 1. (or I should say in the opposite order)

@KurtG. can I  find the inverse? I only found the Jacobian. If so , do you have a link to such a case?

A link? What system of equations do you have to solve to find the inverse? Own efforts please.

I have to rephrase a new question for that. Let me do that

No, the  other question is about finding the inverse. This question in the OP is about proving its existence.

Finding the inverse will automatically prove its existence. A tremendous number of posts for such a simple task.

This system
\begin{align}
u&=x+y+z^2\,,\\
v&=x-y+z\,,\\
w&=2x+y-z\,
\end{align}
can be solved:
\begin{align}
v+w&=3x\,,\tag{gives you $x$}\\
u+v&=2x+z^2+z=\tfrac32(v+w)+z^2+z\,,\tag{gives you $z$}\\
y&=x-v+z\,.\tag{gives you $y$}
\end{align}

It can be solved, but it doesn't look neat?

You haven't seen something ugly yet it seems.

hilarious reponse! Thanks

Let \begin{align}
x+y+z^2&=v &&\\
x-y+z&=u&&\\
2x+y-z&=w
\end{align}
In this system, $v,u,w$ are expressed in terms of $x,y,z$. Can you express $x,y,z$ in terms of $v,u,w$?

Yes, you can, but you can't isolate $x,y,z$ from one another

@Superunknown Ok, let's denote the Jacobian you found by $J$. Now, $J$ is invertible iff det$(J)\neq 0$. You can check that det$(J)=6z+3. $ So, your function is locally invertible at points $(x,y,z)$ which satisfy $6z+3\neq 0$

Thanks user9... !
